# Comma after adverb

Tags: formatting, grammar, journalism, article

Should you include a comma after an adverb, just before the adverb or not include a comma at all in this example. The adverb in question being  'prematurely'.

1 On Tuesday, the EU’s attempt to reach a unanimous position calling, prematurely, for an immediate ceasefire was scuppered by Hungary.

2 On Tuesday, the EU’s attempt to reach a unanimous position calling, prematurely for an immediate ceasefire was scuppered by Hungary.

3 On Tuesday, the EU’s attempt to reach a unanimous position calling prematurely for an immediate ceasefire was scuppered by Hungary.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set it apart as a parenthetical word with commas before and after it (#1) or not at all if the sentence is clear without them (#3).